# Galaxy Nexus 4 Gives EditText it's own Styling

Tags: android, android-edittext, galaxy

For some reason EditText appears like this in a Galaxy Nexus 4 (Only phone i'm away of atm) works fine on Nexus 5. I've tried everything but can't seem to get anything to work. Any help?
Image : https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-hPFFo5dmsaI/U6SBCdm_hVI/AAAAAAAACvI/yZRbJN_wzfU/w346-h192/14+-+1

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etFTName"
            style="@style/customTextEdit"
            android:hint="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etFTQty"
            style="@style/customTextEdit"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="Qty."/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etFTPrice"
            style="@style/customTextEdit"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Price"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="__"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:id="@+id/tvFTRemove"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: don't use device default theme..

Comment: @k0sh I'm not, I am using android:Theme.Holo.Light

Comment: Hmmmm.!What is the customEditText theme???

Comment: @k0sh Just margins: <style name="customTextEdit" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">15dp</item>
    </style>

Comment: In your manifest set the theme as this @android:style/Theme.Holo"

Comment: @k0sh didn't help, still shows it the same.